# How do I add roll to Pitch and Yaw?

Tags: trigonometry

How to get the effect of a roll axis as a sum of yaw and pitch axes?

I have two axes, and I need to add 'roll' to them in a way that would change the yaw/pitch but not actually add a roll third axis.
I don't really know what calculations to use for this, and I couldn't really figure out how to do such a thing without adding a third axis.

[image]

the red dot in this picture shows an example pitch/yaw, as an example, imagine the yaw is 0 and the pitch is 25.
the green circle shows 'fake roll'.
how would I apply, using an equation of some sort, 35 degrees of roll to the red dot to move its position to the blue dot's.

thanks in advance, sorry for my improper capitalization.

Comment: If you yaw by $90$ degrees, then the (rotated) pitch axis will align with the original roll axis.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what rotations you are trying to do. If I understood correctly I think the resulting point will be here:

(sin(25)*cos(35), sin(25)*sin(35))